# Objective c Format float with comma and 2 decimal places

Tags: objective-c, formatter

I am trying to format my float into something like this "3,343,000.55" and turn it into a string.

Using the code below, I get something like this "3,343,000.00".

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myFloat];
    NSString *myFor = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNum];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just replace this below line

```
//it will change your value as double
NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:3343000.55];
```

just change from `numberWithInt` to `numberWithDouble`